# Report with Salesforce knowledge votes is getting weird results

Tags: knowledge, lightning-knowledge

I am trying to build a report with Salesforce knowledge articles and votes. In order to achieve that, I have built a report type for knowledge articles and article vote statistics.

However, when I built and run the report, it shows something like this:

[image]

Please note that all the 5 records are pointing to one single knowledge article. And I have only one knowledge article. It seems to me to be something like a historic tracking instead of a up-to-date vote report. Is there a way I can get only the latest count of thumbs up and thumbs down?

Comment: How many article versions you have? It could be per each version which makes sense.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I got only one version I suppose. That's weirdest part

Comment: Can you pull in the Channel field as well? It could be per channel then.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Yes, you are right. it is per channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest pulling the fields like Channel and Duration and Related Role fields. This is documented in the help article [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_custom_reports_fields.htm&type=5)

Also, use the Count field on the votes and not cumulative count. You might need to filter based on the channel or Duration to get the result.

The other option is to use a soql on [ArticleVoteStat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticlevotestat.htm) object and this will give you proper weighted average score.